# obj[arr[i]] not equal to arr[i]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to store some settings in an object. The problem however is that `obj[arr[i]]` is not the same value as `arr[i]`

```
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (players[i].volume < 1) players[i].volume = (Math.round((players[i].volume + 0.1) * 10) / 10); // JS math error fix
        settings[players[i]] = settings[players[i]] || players[i];
        settings[players[i]].volume = players[i].volume;
        console.log(settings[players[i]].id + " " + players[i].id + " " + players[i].volume);
    }
```

`console.log` will return this: "music music 0" which is fine, but next it will return:
"music speech 0" while I expected it to return "speech speech 0"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23yJS/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `players[i]` is an object, when you do `settings[players[i]]` it will be converted to a string to make an array index. But all your objects probably have the same `toString` value, something like `"[object Object]"`. So, all your `player[i]`'s will be stored at `settings["[object Object]"]`.

You can see what's going on here if you inspect the value of `settings` in a debugger.

Comment: That works, but can you tell me why `settings[players[i].id] = settings[players[i].id] || players[i].id;
      settings[players[i].id].volume = players[i].volume;` doesn't work? Volume will be undefined.